# Задать имя возвращаемого массива json в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Ссылка http://udeveloper.ru/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=9 возвращает такой json примерно:

```
[
  {
    "date": "07.12.2017 20:12:21",
    "date_gmt": "07.12.2017 17:12:21",
    "featured_image_thumbnail_url": "http://udeveloper.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Kak-sdelat-shablon-s-nulja-dlja-Joomla-3.x-Stranica-error-404.jpg",
    "title": "Как сделать шаблон с нуля для Joomla 3.x (Страница &#171;error 404&#187;)",
    "content": "<p>В данном уроке мы с вами сделаем страницу <strong>error 404</strong>. Что же это такое? Среди веб-мастеров есть такая шутка, что <strong>страница 404</strong> это самая посещаемая страница в интернете.</p>"
  },
    {
    "date": "07.12.2017 20:12:21",
    "date_gmt": "07.12.2017 17:12:21",
    "featured_image_thumbnail_url": "http://udeveloper.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Kak-sdelat-shablon-s-nulja-dlja-Joomla-3.x-Stranica-error-404.jpg",
    "title": "Как сделать шаблон с нуля для Joomla 3.x (Страница &#171;error 404&#187;)",
    "content": "<p>В данном уроке мы с вами сделаем страницу <strong>error 404</strong>. Что же это такое? Среди веб-мастеров есть такая шутка, что <strong>страница 404</strong> это самая посещаемая страница в интернете.</p>"
  }
]
```

У этого массива нет имени. Возможно ли задать ему имя чтобы на выходе получить например такое:

```
{
  "postslist": [
    {
      "date": "07.12.2017 20:12:21",
      "date_gmt": "07.12.2017 17:12:21",
      "featured_image_thumbnail_url": "http://udeveloper.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Kak-sdelat-shablon-s-nulja-dlja-Joomla-3.x-Stranica-error-404.jpg",
      "title": "Как сделать шаблон с нуля для Joomla 3.x (Страница &#171;error 404&#187;)",
      "content": "<p>В данном уроке мы с вами сделаем страницу <strong>error 404</strong>. Что же это такое? Среди веб-мастеров есть такая шутка, что <strong>страница 404</strong> это самая посещаемая страница в интернете.</p>"
    },
    {
      "date": "07.12.2017 20:12:21",
      "date_gmt": "07.12.2017 17:12:21",
      "featured_image_thumbnail_url": "http://udeveloper.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Kak-sdelat-shablon-s-nulja-dlja-Joomla-3.x-Stranica-error-404.jpg",
      "title": "Как сделать шаблон с нуля для Joomla 3.x (Страница &#171;error 404&#187;)",
      "content": "<p>В данном уроке мы с вами сделаем страницу <strong>error 404</strong>. Что же это такое? Среди веб-мастеров есть такая шутка, что <strong>страница 404</strong> это самая посещаемая страница в интернете.</p>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте такой код в functions.php

```
/**
 * Filters the API response.
 *
 * Allows modification of the response data after inserting
 * embedded data (if any) and before echoing the response data.
 *
 * @since 4.8.1
 *
 * @param array            $result  Response data to send to the client.
 * @param WP_REST_Server   $_this    Server instance.
 * @param WP_REST_Request  $request Request used to generate the response.
 *
 * @return array            Response data to send to the client.
 */
function filter_rest_pre_echo_response( $result, $_this, $request ) {
    $new_result = array(
        'postlist' => $result,
    );
    return $new_result;
}

add_filter( 'rest_pre_echo_response', 'filter_rest_pre_echo_response', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось